# Find a recursive definition for the sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

The first sequence given is 3, 7, 16, 41, 77,....
I really am quite stuck on this because I can't seem to find any relationship between one term and the terms prior to it. I first noticed that it seemed like we were adding a perfect square to each one, since 3+4=7, 7+9=16, etc. But we skipped over adding the perfect square of 16 to anything so that must not be a useful idea.

The next problem is a recursive sequence given by $3s_{n-1}+2$ and I need to write it as a closed-form formula. I believe I should use something involving $3^n$ and I have tried subtracting $2^n$ but it only works for the first two terms.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is a mistake: either it was intended to be $3,7,16,32,57,\ldots$, corresponding to the description $s_1=3$, $s_n=s_{n-1}+n^2$ for $n>1$, or there is simply not enough information to allow one to guess how it is intended to differ from that sequence.

For the second one you can try ‘unwinding’ it:

$$\begin{align*}
s_n&=3s_{n-1}+2\\
&=3(3s_{n-2}+2)+2\\
&=3^2s_{n-2}+3\cdot2+2\\
&=3^2(3s_{n-3}+2)+3\cdot2+2\\
&=3^3s_{n-3}+3^2\cdot2+3\cdot2+2\\
&\;\vdots\\
&=3^ks_{n-k}+3^{k-1}\cdot2+3^{k-2}\cdot2+\ldots+3\cdot2+2\\
&=3^ks_{n-k}+2\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}3^\ell\;.
\end{align*}$$

Depending on whether the first term that you’re given is $s_0$ or $s_1$, you can unwind it to $k=n$ or $k=n-1$ to get an expression for $s_n$ in terms of $n$. That expression will still contain a summation, but it’s the sum of a geometric series, so you can get it in closed form.

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem,

$s_n=3s_{n-1}+2 \implies s_{n-1}=3s_{n-2}+2$

$\therefore s_n-4s_{n-1}+3s_{n-2}=0$

Therefore the [characteristic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Theorem) is $t^2-4t+3=0$. Can you take it from here?